# I keep getting Connot GET /auth/twitter/callback in my callbackURL when using passport. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, express, passport-twitter

I have seen similar posts with this problem, but none of those answers seemed to fix my issue. Including the missing hyphen in a couple answers.

When I send the user to Twitter to get authenticated using Passport, the broswer says I have no GET handler for my callbackURL. I am super confused since I believe I do have it handled, but its not working.

**In my app.js file I have:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static("node_modules/bootstrap/dist"));
app.use(express.static("node_modules/jquery/dist"));
app.use(express.static('img'));

app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret:'prince', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

var authRouter = require('./admin/auth');
app.use("/admin/login", authRouter);
var frontPageFlow = require('./index');
app.get('/', frontPageFlow, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: "Crowd District"
    });
});
```

**In my Auth.js file I have:**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

router.get('/auth/twitter',
    passport.authenticate('twitter'),
    function (req, res) {
        res.render('login')
    });


router.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
    passport.authenticate('twitter', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    }));

router.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.render("login");
    })
    .post(passport.authenticate('twitter', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/admin/login'
        })

);

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: 'Consumer key here',
    consumerSecret: 'Consumer secret here',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:9000/auth/twitter/callback'


    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, cb) {
        User.findOrCreate({ twitterId: profile.displayName }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return cb(null, profile); }

            if (!user){
                user = new User ({
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    email: profile.emails[0].value,
                    username: profile.username,
                    provider: 'twitter'
                });
                user.save(function (err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    console.log("successful user entry!");

                    return done(err, user);

                });
            } else {
                return done(err, user);
            }

        });
    }
));
```

**And my userModel.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
module.exports = router;

var schemaOptions = {
    collection: "users"
};

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({

    id           : String,
    token        : String,
    displayName  : String,
    username     : String

}, schemaOptions);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

No matter what I do, or rearrange the order of operations, I continue to get in my callback:

```
Cannot GET /auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=enfwejngfon2804&oauth_verifier=LK35h5988gieunrgbr4ghghi
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If those are your actual Twitter Key/Secret then go to https://apps.twitter.com/ NOW and revoke/regenerate them.

Comment: @Prinzhorn Thank you for the heads up. I regenerated it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route paths are incorrect because you are using `app.use("/admin/login", authRouter);` which makes all routes in that file have a prefix `'/admin/login'`, so instead of `'/auth/twitter/callback'`, you code is expecting `'/admin/login/auth/twitter/callback'`. Get all your paths to line up and you'll be in better shape. I recommend avoiding mount prefixes when calling `app.use`. They just lead to this kind of confusion. Just use `app.use(authRouter);` and make your route paths absolute paths. They are much more straightforward to work with.